# What is a bootnode exactly?

Tags: go-ethereum

Is a bootnode a clone of a fullnode or a lightnode? Can a bootnode mine with cpu or gpu? Should a bootnode's enode address be known by default by other miners and fullnodes, or can they discover this bootnode somehow?

Answer (score 3):

It is advisable to not have so many questions all group together when asking a question.

1. Is a bootnode a clone of a fullnode or a lightnode?

A. It would be a full node.

2. Can a bootnode mine with cpu or gpu?

A. Go based ethereum nodes can mine with CPU and GPU. Due to hashrate needed only GPU mining is profitable on the public Ethereum network.  On a private deployment you can mine with CPU.

3. Should a bootnode's enode address be known by default by other
   miners and fullnodes, or can they discover this bootnode somehow?

A. Several bootnode enodes are embedded in the code by default https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/params/bootnodes.go through these bootnodes a node can join the network and find other nodes.